# How to work with git, maven and versioning correclty

Tags: git, maven, versioning, git-flow, jgitflow-maven-plugin

We are starting a first project with git (stash/bamboo). Before we used svn. We are building java projects with maven and have to maintain multiple staging environments before we go to production. And this is the difference to the examples I found on the web.

How do you use git together with maven and support multiple staging environments.
I think to use git together with maven the jgitflow plugin is nice. But there you cannot really support the staging environments. Everything I find is missing something to have a perfect integration of all our needs. But I think what we do is common for a lot of companies.

How do you do it?

Comment: I don't really see how Maven has anything to do with your source code and Git.  Maven builds your source code and Git versions it.  Can you elaborate on where the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, this I din't really mention. The whole versioning is in my point of view linked to the git flow. I don't want to do a release with a lot of manual steps I prefer to have as less interaction as possible. That's why we use the jgitflow plugin.